# Login into WSO2 through google

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, google-authentication, wso2-identity-server

I have successfully installed WSO2 on my ubuntu machine and I was able to login into google account using WSO2, by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4rIuwSiUmI). But I want to do the opposite of it. I want to login into WSO2 using google. I am unable t find any tutorials regarding it. Please provide steps to follow to do it.

Answer (score 3):

For this purpose you can use Google as a federated authenticator in WSO2 Identity Server. Follow steps in [1] to configure the Identity Server to authenticate users using their Google user accounts.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Configuring+Google